# R: Nonlinear optimization with equality constraints

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions, nlopt

I have  a `TxN` matrix `M` and a `Nx1`  weight vector `w`, where `sum(w)=1`.
I need to find the `w`, which maximises the number of positive elements in `Mw`.
If there is no single `w`, the maximum possible value for  `Mw` is desired.

More formally, denote with `M_t` the `t`-row in `M`, then I need

```
max_w  Sum_t I(M_t w)
sub    1'w=1
```

where `1` is the vector of ones and the function `I(x)` returns `1`, if `x` is positive, and `0` otherwise.

Note: if dividing the objective function by `T`, the summands can be thought as frequencies of a weighted sum of random variables.

Data can be simulated as follows:

```
N <- 4
set.seed(1)
M <-  matrix(rnorm(200), ncol=N)
w <- as.matrix(rep(1/N, N))
one <- as.matrix(rep(1, N))
```

The objective function and the constraint are:

```
I <- function(r) as.numeric(r>0)
f <- function(x) -sum(sapply(M %*% x, I))
h <- function(x) t(one) %*% x - 1
```

Now in R one possibility could be [nloptr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/index.html):

```
library(nloptr)
local_opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG_EQ",
                    "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7 )
opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG_EQ",
              "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7,
              "maxeval" = 100000,
              "local_opts" = local_opts,
              "print_level" = 2)

nloptr( x0=as.vector(w),  eval_f=f, eval_g_eq=h, opts=opts)
```

I get:

> NLopt solver status: -4 ( NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED: Roundoff errors led to a 
>   breakdown of the optimization algorithm. In this case, the returned minimum may 
>   still be useful.
>   Number of Iterations....: 17530
>   Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-07    maxeval: 1e+05
>   [...]
>   Current value of objective function:  -33
>   Current value of controls: 0.5175225 0.1124845 0.1598906 0.2101024

Note that 17530 iterations are far less than maxeval (100000).

I don't know how to correctly use  `NLOPT_GN_ISRES`, which could potentially give speed improvements. Replacing `NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG_EQ` with `NLOPT_GN_ISRES` gives:

> NLopt solver status: -2 ( NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS: Invalid arguments (e.g. lower 
>       bounds are bigger than upper bounds, an unknown algorithm was specified, 
>       etcetera). )

I am new to nloptr, so I would like to know what follows.

As I understand my result for `f` (-33) is reliable with a tolerance of 1.0e-7. Is this correct?
How can I state whether the value for `w`is unique?
What is the syntax for `NLOPT_GN_ISRES`?
The objective `f` contains an implicit `if` condition, can I still use a (numerical) gradient?
Are other packages, such as alabama, better at this type of problems?

*Update* Changed starting point to `w`.

Comment: That is interesting. I couldn't replicate this; I have no problems going above 19605 evaluations. But I do run into `NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED` errors. The best I got was 33 positive elements. Using `Rsolnp` with the following: `mdl = solnp(w, f, eqfun = h, eqB = 0, control = list(delta = 5))` I got 34.

Comment: @spinodal: Thanks, I changed the starting point to w (equally weighted sum) and now my results are like yours (please, see update). I still would like to fix `NLOPT_GN_ISRES` and understand the implication of `NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED`. If it is only a matter of a better approximation, the result would be totally acceptable.